# Doubt regarding sets in apex

Tags: apex

i have declared a set of id's. I initially added 2 different account id's to set as below

```
 Set<id> acctSet = new Set<id>();
 acctset.add('001c000000g0ijo');
 acctset.add('001c000000g0iFJ');
 system.debug('***acctSet:'+acctset);
```

Now for each of the above Accounts, they have 2 to 3 contacts respectively. Now i am querying them.

```
 List<Contact> Cons = new List<Contact>([select id, AccountId from Contact where accountid IN :   acctSet ORDER BY CreatedDate ASC NULLS LAST LIMIT 1]);
system.debug('***cons:'+cons);
```

Now the above results shows only one account and its related contact(As i Limited result to 1).  is this the correct behavior of sets or am i missing something. My expected output is like it should get related first created contact for both accounts.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The limit of 1 limits the results to 1 record TOTAL not one per account

If you want 1 per account your query would have to be

```
[Select ID, (select id, AccountId from Contacts ORDER BY CreatedDate ASC LIMIT 1) From Account where ID IN :   acctSet];
```